# Want to delete existing document from folder and database values from table using transaction in hibernate query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have an application with document uploading.After uploading the document,the document path is newly created and the document is saved within the file path.At the same time the document path and related values are saved with in the database table.In my application after uploading,there is a button to delete the unwanted document.Sometimes the document deletion operation is not properly work.So there is a wastage of memory will occur.I want to avoid the situation by using transaction statement.I don't know how to use the hibernate transaction to my work.Is this possible? Please help me to do the work successfully(I am using spring with hibernate integration and postgresql)

Thank you

In controller

```
int supDocId=1102;
String docPath=D:/;
String filePath=docPath+supDocId+".pdf";
File file=new File(filePath);
boolean isDelete = servicesService.deleteDocument(supDocId);
if(isDelete)
{
if(file.exists())
    {
        file.delete();
    }
alertMsg = "The file is deleted sucessfully";   
    }
   else{
   alertMsg = "Deletion Failed.!!!  File is under processing..";    
}
```

In service class

```
public boolean deleteDocument(int supDocId){
    return servicesDAO.deleteDocument(supDocId);
}
```

In servicesDAO class

```
public boolean deleteDocument(int supDocId){
int deleteStatus=0;
try {
  String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  tablename  WHERE attch_doc_id='"+supDocId+"'";
 Query deleteQ = session.createSQLQuery(deleteQuery);
 deleteStatus  = deleteQ.executeUpdate();                                       
 if(deleteStatus>0){    
   return deleteStatus;         
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return deleteStatus;    
}
```

I want to work the two operations(document and database value deletion) within the DAO class using transaction statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DB transaction fails - you will have problem not only with deleted files, but also with uploaded new files.

In most cases file system does not supports transaction so I don't think bullet proof solution can be achieved using XA (distributed transactions using the JTA) or similar approach.

Quite strait forward solution I am using in some of my projects:

1. Files in file system are **created before DB commit** (but preferably after hibernate flush).
2. On file delete operation, reference to file is deleted from DB, but not from  file system.
3. **Asynchronous process periodically scans all files in file system and deletes files with no references from DB.**

If you have big number of files some optimization can be necessary to prevent always scan all files. For example:

1. Put new files to folder with name "current date", so only part of files can be checked for unsuccessful transactions involving uploaded new files.
2. On file delete operation insert new record to table "deleted_files" with reference to file that should be deleted.
3. Create asynchronous process to periodically scans table "deleted_files", which deletes physical file and if deletion is successful (or file already is missing) removes record from table "deleted_files" and commits transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `+supDocId+` Replace that with `?` instead or you would be leaving yourself vulnerable to **Sql Injection**.

And `deleteQ.Execute();`is what you want to be doing not an update because you want to be checking boolean true or false if something is deleted.